# how to split up an object in powershell to the correct JSON format

Tags: json, powershell, hashtable

I have an object that returns

```
Name         Value
----         -----
field_1      abc
field_2      123
```

I'm creating the object using this function:

```
function CreateParamFileObject($schema,$contentVersion,$parameters)
{

    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    $obj |  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name '$schema' -Value $schema
    $obj |  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "contentVersion" -Value $contentVersion   
    $obj |  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "parameters" -Value $parameters

    #foreach ($key in $obj.parameters.Keys)
    #{

    #}

   return,$obj
```

The "parameters" param is coming in as a hashtable that looks like this:

```
$paramsphase1 = @{
                field_1 = "abc";
                field_2 =(123)
```

when I convert it to JSON, it looks like:

```
"parameters":  {
                       "field_1":  "abc",
                       "field_2":  "123",
               }
```

I want it to look like this:

```
"parameters": {
        "field_1": {
            "value": "abc"
        },
        "field_2": {
            "value": 123
        },
```

Is there an easier way to do this in powershell? I've tried a few functions but haven't been able to achieve the correct results.

Comment: How did you create your object. If you show us it gets easier to show you solutions that match your process better. You just need to embed another object for field_1's value.

Comment: Please [edit] any relevant details into your question. Code is horrible in comments and that makes it so people will see all the relevant information in the question.

Comment: I edited my code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code that does a conversion.

```
# object
$d1 = @{}
$d1.parameters = @{}
$d1.parameters.field1 = 'abc'
$d1.parameters.field2 = '123'

$d1 | ConvertTo-Json

# conversion
$d2 = @{}
$d2.parameters = @{}
foreach ($k1 in $d1.parameters.Keys)
{
    $d2.parameters.$k1 = @{}    
    $d2.parameters.$k1.value = $d1.parameters.$k1
}

$d2 | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: This would be better with an explanation of what the code does, how it works, where the asker went wrong in her code, etc.